# How many pins can you reliably represent using the Bing Maps API?

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I'm trying to build a maps of pictures using the Bing Maps API.  The idea is that the entire map would be covered in pictures.   I'm wondering if I should use a tile layer or pins.   I'm wondering what the upper limit is on the pins you can render on a map.

Comment: Found something that might help you: [Bing Pins](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/how-many-pins-can-bing-maps-handle-in.html)

Comment: There isn't an hardcoded limit. It simply gets slower, depending obviously on the CPU but also the browser used. One viable approach is to create clusters of pins, or just limit per zoom the amount of drawn objects